# CKEditor 4.3 Inline Save button

Tags: yii, save, ckeditor, inline

I need to upgrade CKEditor 4.0 to 4.3. Everything is fine except the InlineCKeditor does not want to work with Save button. I get error : `"Uncaught TypeError: Object Esave has no method 'render' "`. Esave is renamed plugin Save http://ckeditor.com/addon/save. I tried to change this plugin to the newest one, renamed it to esave, and used it without renaming but still get same error. 
What should I change to make Save button work again?

This is the InlineCKeditor code where error is from:

```
<?php
Yii::import('ext.widgets.inline.InlineEdit');
class InlineCKeditor extends InlineEdit
{
    /**
     * @var string path for CKeditor init script
     */
    protected $tinyMceInitPath;

    protected function loadCustomScript()
    {
        parent::loadCustomScript();
        $this->scriptLogics();
        Yii::app()->wysiwyg->getWysiwyg();
    }    
    protected function scriptLogics()
    {
        $script = "    
        CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'esave,doNothing';    
        // The 'instanceCreated' event is fired for every editor instance created.
        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( event ) {
            var editor = event.editor,
                element = editor.element;

            // Customize editors for headers and tag list.
            // These editors don't need features like smileys, templates, iframes etc.

            if ( $.inArray('ckeditor',element.$.classList) >= 0 ) {
                // Customize the editor configurations on 'configLoaded' event,
                // which is fired after the configuration file loading and
                // execution. This makes it possible to change the
                // configurations before the editor initialization takes place.    
                editor.on( 'configLoaded', function() {    
                    // Remove unnecessary plugins to make the editor simpler.
                    editor.config.removePlugins = 'colorbutton,find,font,' +
                        'forms,iframe,newpage,removeformat,scayt,flash,' +
                        'smiley,stylescombo,templates,wsc, pagebreak';

                    // Rearrange the layout of the toolbar.

                    editor.config.toolbarGroups = [
                        { name: 'editing',      groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'links' ] },
                        { name: 'insert'},
                        { name: 'undo' },
                        '/',
                        { name: 'styles'},
                        { name: 'indents',      groups: ['list', 'align','bidi']},
                        { name : 'others', items : [ 'Esave' ] }

                    ];

                });
            }else{
                editor.on( 'configLoaded', function() {

                    editor.config.keystrokes =
                    [
                        //deleted
                    ];

                    editor.config.removePlugins = 'a11yhelp,about,basicstyles,bidi,blockquote,' +
                     'clipboard, colorbutton, colordialog,contextmenu,dialog,dialogui,div,elementspath,' +
                     'enterkey,entities,filebrowser,find,flash,floatpanel,font,format,' +
                     'forms,horizontalrule,htmlwriter,iframe,image,indent,justify,link,list,listblock,liststyle,magicline,' +
                     'maximize,menu,menubutton,newpage,panel,panelbutton,pastefromword,pastetext,popup,preview,print,' +
                     'removeformat,resize,richcombo,save,scayt,selectall,showblocks,showborders,smiley,sourcearea,specialchar,stylescombo,' +
                     'tab,table,tabletools,templates,wsc,wysiwygarea';

                    editor.config.toolbarGroups = [{ name : 'others', items : [ 'Esave' ] }];   
                });
            }
        });
        ";    
        Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('editor_rules', $script, CClientScript::POS_BEGIN);
    }    
    protected function getEditableClass()
    {
        return 'ckeditor edit_' . static::$innerIncrement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's related somehow with Yii?

About CKEditor plugins — you can't just rename it in config, so problem is mostly here.